# Speed up web application development cycle + code hot-swap

Tags: scala, sbt

I am relatively new to the development of JVM web applications and still relatively new to Scala development too. I see clear benefits of this approach but I need to somewhat persuade rest of my team to like it as I do.

I have currently written a content management system on top of Scalatra framework. I found quickly my design quite silly as it looks like this (schematically):

```
class MyServlet extends MyStack with Plugin1 with Plugin2 with Plugin3 //etc.
trait Plugin1 { self: MyServlet => /*...*/ }
trait Plugin2 { self: MyServlet with Plugin1 => /*...*/ }
// etc.
```

Simply decompose the functionality in traits, "resolve" dependencies through self-types and compose the main class out of these traits. This works quite fine except for two things: there is no isolation of code (one has to be aware of other traits) and my main problem for now is the speed of compilation (and seeing the changes get live).

I am using SBT incremental compilation now. Like this when I make some modification to some of the traits that comes early in the chain, it is likely that many classes get invalidated and the compilation takes ages (with container restart it is often around a minute for my still very small application). And my colleagues are used to untyped scripted languages - being able to see their changes instantly.

I am about to rewrite my application in such a way that this problem is at least significantly alleviated. I guess the first thing I should do is to make the application modules more independent (probably using Dependency Injection). But I was thinking about taking it further and allow the modules to be swapped for a new version in the runtime (i.e. even without restarting the container). I know there is JRebel, but I would like to stick with free solutions for now.

I have come up with an idea of solution, but I am not sure whether it is doable. A module in my web application would typically hook up on some routes and provide some public interface to the rest of the application. (Let's assume interface `MyModule` and an implementation `MyModuleImpl`)

```
def use[T]: Usage[T]
```

One would then be able to use `use[MyModule]` to get its dependency (fairly similar concept to DI). However in comparison to DI it wouldn't inject an instance of `MyModuleImpl` directly, instead it would wrap it inside an `Usage[T]`. This class might look as follows (in its simplest form):

```
class Usage[T] {
  def get: T
}
```

I would like that the `get` method returns the "latest" instance of `T`. One could provide new source code for any class implementing interface `T` - and if it is possible to compile it against the currently loaded `T`, the `Usage[T]` instance for `T` gets instance of new implementation of `T` and any subsequent calls to `get` would return this instance. (So any module will be transparently using the new version of `T` further on)

Is this possible to implement a system like this (ideally with help of some existing libraries like Scaldi for the DI part) or is it more like an utopia which is impossible to achieve? Or what you would suggest me to speed up the development cycle?

Comment: Have you considered using Play v2.3 framework? It supports DI and other nifty stuff. Moreover, you can manage the server and auto on-demand compilation using Typesafe activator. I recommend seeing some videos - it's a great way of coding scala webpages

Comment: I have experimented with Play in past (some older versions, 2.1 if I remember correctly). I liked it in many aspects - but I somehow found it quite limiting for me. What I disliked the most was that the routes were defined through a specialized file. I had the impression that this basically limits the ability of plugins to create their own routes. I haven't dug much in this field though.

Comment: I see, well I build very basic apps so I can't judge. Anyway, Typesafe Activator is amazing piece of software.